# Fetch all specific customer's order using Customer token in magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, rest-api

I am aware about method using **admin token**

> Request type :: **GET**

**URL**

```
http://<host>/rest/V1/orders
?searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field]=customer_email
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=someone@test.com
```

**Authentication** `Bearer <Admin token>`

But how to Fetch all specific customer's order using **Customer token** in magento 2 REST API ?

Comment: You can use integration token or admin token as the acl permission for this is admin or else you can create a new endpoint with customer access.

Comment: Can you please explain how ? Programmatically in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is using resource `Magento_Sales::sales` because of this we can't access it using **Customer's token** so for the same we need to **override** Specific **API** with

`<resource ref="self" />`

And using this we can access all orders of specific customer using **customer's Token** in Magento API.

```
<route url="/V1/orders" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow this blog, you will get all Customer's orders by REST API using the token

http://wikicoode.com/magento2/get-customers-orders-using-magento2-api-rest

Comment: I am aware about method using admin token

Comment: I want use customer token